# How can i get data from service in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have `LoginController` and `securityService`.

This is LoginCtrl

```
// place the message if something goes wrong
$scope.authMsg = '';
$scope.login = function () {
        $scope.authMsg = '';
        var loginData = {email: $scope.account.email, password: $scope.account.password};
        securityService.login(loginData);
    };
```

This is securityService

```
login: function (logData) {
    var _vm = this;

    $http
        .post('/api-token-auth/', logData)
        .then(function (response) {
            // assumes if ok, response is an object with some data, if not, a string with error
            // customize according to your api
            if (!response.data.token) {
                _vm.authMsg = 'Incorrect credentials.';
            } else {
                $cookieStore.put('djangotoken', response.data.token);
                $http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = 'JWT ' + response.data.token;
                $http.get('/api/account/restricted/').then(function (response) {
                    authService.loginConfirmed();
                    _vm.currentUser = response.data;
                    $rootScope.currentUser = response.data;

                });
            }
        }, function (x) {
            _vm.authMsg = 'Server Request Error';
        });
},
```

This login is working fine but my problem is i don't know how can get the `authMesg` from service to controller because that is async. Everytime i get blank message in case of invalid login

Comment: Make use of `promises` inside your service. Angular has `$q` right. Use it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to use promise service of angular to make you controller and service syn

```
 login: function (logData) {
                    var _vm = this,d= $$q.defer();

                    $http
                        .post('/api-token-auth/', logData)
                        .then(function (response) {
                            // assumes if ok, response is an object with some data, if not, a string with error
                            // customize according to your api
                            if (!response.data.token) {
                                _vm.authMsg = 'Incorrect credentials.';
                            } else {
                                $cookieStore.put('djangotoken', response.data.token);
                                $http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = 'JWT ' + response.data.token;
                                $http.get('/api/account/restricted/').then(function (response) {
                                    authService.loginConfirmed();
                                    _vm.currentUser = response.data;
                                    $rootScope.currentUser = response.data;

                                });
                            }
                            d.resolve(vm.authMsg);

                        }, function (x) {
                            _vm.authMsg = 'Server Request Error';
                              d.reject(vm.authMsg);
                        });
                },
```

In controller you need to resolve this promise

```
securityService.login(loginData).then(function(data){
 consol.log(data); // get success data

},function(error){
   consol.log(data); // get error message data 
})
```

and inject **$q** in your service.

Comment: so `data` will be whatever we put in `resolve(data)` or `reject(data)` ?

Answer (score 0):

This will give you `authMsg`

```
securityService.login(loginData).authMsg
```

But follow @Vigneswaran Marimuthu comments, that is best practice.